# Aerodynamics and thermodynamic

Tags: thermodynamics, aerodynamics

Why can we refer an object as being aerodynamic but we can't refer an object as being thermodynamic, and if an object is thermodynamic what does it even means?

Comment: Why do we drive on the parkway and park in the driveway?  My point is that English is not consistent in meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling something *aerodynamic* is shorthand for calling it *aerodynamically efficient*.

There's nothing wrong with referring to a system as *thermodynamically efficient*, it's just that this isn't usually shortened to *thermodynamic*.

Comment: It may also mean having good aerodynamical properties (for example low drag). Term _good aerodynamical properties_ isn't that unambiguous though.

Comment: Isn't *low drag* basically the same as *aerodynamically efficient*?

Comment: Drag isn't the only aerodynamical property, although probably the most important one. When I hear _efficient_ I immediately think about _efficiency_, i.e. "concept, quantitatively determined by the ratio of output to input". I'm not sure how to define input and output in aerodynamics in the proper way. Btw, I'm not contesting Your answer :)

Comment: In my first comment I meant _good thermodynamical properties_ of course :)